# Why diff stackexchange site for programmer

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, stack-exchange

Why do we have a diff stackexchange site for programmers, IMO it needlessly duplicates functionality of stackoverflow

Comment: I'd advise against reading Meta on Programmers SE. Due to shifting domains, topics and rulesets, it opens more questions than it answers.

Comment: From the answers it seems that there has been a long back and forth about this so even though I am not sure about the criteria I think there is no point in reopening the debate, if I knew about the background probably I wouldn't have asked the question. Having said that a. Looking at the questions asked on overflow it seems criteria is "More honor'd in the breach than the observance"  b. I don't who downvoted the q but that was not very nice, I hope he/she doesn't kick cute puppies in real life for fun.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why was the Programmers site on Stack Exchange created?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64042/why-was-the-programmers-site-on-stack-exchange-created)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a lot of history that led up to the decision to maintain separate sites. There was a continuous, low-level, mostly mannerly, but none-the-less deeply rooted feud over the proper boundaries of on-topicness for Stack Overflow starting as far back as the beta.

The establishment of Programmers has relieved some of the pressure, and I think the situation continues to improve as the community adjusts to the change.

Answer (score 6):

Please read the faq for both sites; it is quite clear what the differences are.

https://stackoverflow.com/faq
https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/faq

If, after reading these faqs, you have *specific* questions, please edit your question to include them.

Comment: actually I asked the question after reading the FAQ =, I know there is a criteria of subjectivity but a. Even after the beta site stackoverflow regularly gets subjective queries as b. it is not very easy to decide what is strictly a subjective question or not, which is not surprising considering c. a lot of programming is about subjective arguments. I would have thought a better idea would have been to have a diff stackexchange based on diff tech (eg web development).Anyhow considering the not very friendly reply I think maybe it was wrong q to ask. My apologies.

Comment: @guarav if it contains code, it generally belongs on Stack Overflow. If it does not, it generally belongs on programmers.se -- it's fairly simple if you use that guideline.

Comment: I think maybe that should be reflected in the FAQ's a bit more strongly. Honestly I've read them a couple of times, and just searched meta to try and find the answer, because after reading them I wasn't sure on the differences. I've seen many a question that don't feature code, where SO seems the right place for them.

Comment: @ian if it is discussiony and has no clear cut right or wrong or even verifiable answer -- this is where *code comes in really freaking handy* -- then it belongs on programmers. But this doesn't exempt people from using their judgment, either.

Answer (score 3):

I think it's a fair question, I was wondering the same myself.

Having read Jeff's links, I summarise it as:

- StackOverflow - How Tos about code
- Programmers - Coding related subjective questions.

Comment: Beware about the "subjective" though. There are more closevoting tendencies on Programmers than on SO.

Comment: @mario: Fair point. From the Programmer's FAQ: "*Stack Exchange is for expert programmers who are interested in subjective discussions on software development."* but also *"Subjective does not mean "anything goes". Please keep it professional at all times. If this is a question you'd be uncomfortable discussing with your colleagues in a work environment, it's probably not appropriate here, either."*