# Where is the "What code would you have on your wedding cake?" question?

Tags: discussion, flags, migration, moderators

[What code would you have on your wedding cake? (old URL)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/686216/what-code-would-you-have-on-your-wedding-cake)

[google cache](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:H9-auyQ8sLEJ:stackoverflow.com/questions/686216/what-code-would-you-have-on-your-wedding-cake+code+wedding+cake)

Where has this question gone? It was closed as off-topic, but it was popular so did not get deleted. Since now we have programmers.SE, I flagged it and suggested moving to p.SE. However the next day the page disappeared without information.

Anyway, I also flagged another question, [Career advice: I am best at what I hate most](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2356044/career-advice-i-am-best-at-what-i-hate-most), and that SO link now automatically redirects to a p.SE question.

What is going on here? Can we get the wedding cake question back? It's funny and popular as well

Comment: It was deleted it two days ago. Jeff cast the final vote; since he's a mod, that vote overrode the question's large number of upvotes.

Comment: If you are searching for some birthday ideas you might want to check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2420689) other old famous question

Comment: @systempuntoout: The cake is a lie.

Comment: Link doesn't work anymore.

Comment: The question was deleted, 10k+ users can see it :-P

Comment: The post was undeleted on Mar 8 '12 at 16:53. Since then, it is back, exactly where it was.

Answer (score 12):

The goal of the StackExchange series of sites is not a secret, it's repeated over and over. Here's a snippet from the [latest blog entry](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/12/stack-overflow-gives-back-2010/) (emphasis from the original):

> We believe our mission as a company is
> to **make the internet better**

While you might convincingly argue that the question did not fit the charter of the site, I believe that it did indeed make the internet better, and the internet is now poorer without it. We do not live by facts and figures alone.

**Edit:** The page was restored in March 2012 with a "Historical Artifact" lock, as described in the blog post https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/03/reputation-and-historical-archives/. The internet feels much better now.

Comment: Good point: deleting those questions from SO makes sense because it makes SO a better place (plus, it is Jeff's site: his rules. No issue there). But it certainly don't make Internet a better place, because said questions were an important part of Internet (thousand of views, hundreds of votes). simply deleting them without archiving them somewhere else is in direct contradiction with the core mission of SO team.

Answer (score 6):

If you're actually just looking for the content that was once in that question, it's in the Wayback Machine:

http://web.archive.org/web/20090330130858/https://stackoverflow.com/questions/686216/what-code-would-you-have-on-your-wedding-cake/686341

Answer (score 3):

See discussion at

[Programmers is about to go live, which questions should we migrate?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/71731/programmers-is-about-to-go-live-which-questions-should-we-migrate)

I am casting the final vote for "delete" on some of these questions that have run their course and have no lasting value.

Comment: Awww man. They should at least be archived statically somewhere in a reliable place.

Comment: -1: deletion without archiving makes no sense for those popular questions. See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/73226/set-up-an-archive-for-legendary-deleted-questions

Comment: Jeff, I cannot believe your soul is so dry.

Comment: I added a rebuttal that does *not* contain any personal attacks. I hope you'll come back to read it.

Comment: wow, very disappointing.