# Is Programmers.SE suddenly going to be flooded with old, unwanted, two year old questions from StackOverflow?

Tags: discussion, migration

Example (one year, nine months old):

https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/30513/as-a-programmer-what-single-discovery-has-given-you-the-greatest-boost-in-product

Will it become the new quest of (certain) high-rep users to aggressively move all of these old questions?  I'm not sure that's a good idea.  It makes Programmers.SE a dumping ground again, which is what we were all trying to avoid in the first place.

Comment: No, not all of them: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/73219/where-is-the-what-code-would-you-have-on-your-wedding-cake-question

Comment: You may flag it for moderator attention and propose to close it off topic. BTW personally I doubt that it is off topic.

Comment: @bernd: To be clear, I meant unwanted on StackOverflow, not necessarily unwanted on Programmers.SE. But now that the migration option exists, will it become the new quest of (certain) high-rep users to aggressively move all of these old questions?  I'm not sure that's a good idea.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Programmers is about to go live, which questions should we migrate? ](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/71731/programmers-is-about-to-go-live-which-questions-should-we-migrate)

Comment: @Shog9: Was there a consensus established there, and will the community follow it?

Comment: @Robert: consensus on what? Jeff's been actively deleting worthless questions, and others have been migrating - if you have thoughts on which sort of questions should/shouldn't be migrated, go share them...

Comment: @Shog9: I don't have any thoughts on that.  I figured I would ask the question and get some discussion about it.  The question you linked is a dog's breakfast.

Comment: @Shog9: These old questions that are now receiving scrutiny because of the newly available migration option have lived on SO for quite some time now without the gears falling out of the universe, so it seems to me the easiest solution would be just to lock them where they are.

Comment: @Robert: I guess my thinking is, if you *don't* want this to happen then participate; if you do or don't care, then don't. As for locking... That's dead-easy, if you happen to be a moderator with time on your hands; it's not really a community action though.

Comment: @Shog: Migrations are not reversible (except by moderators) so how would he participate if he did *not* want these migrations?

Comment: @Aarobot: Rob's a fairly experienced SO user; I'm sure he knows how to use the 10K tools, comment, vote to re-open, flag for moderator attention, etc. But I was referring specifically to participating *in that thread* - making an argument for what should/shouldn't be migrated.

Comment: @bernd_k: The migrated question got closed on Programmers.SE two hours ago. So it is apparently now on its way to deletion.

Comment: @Shog9: It's pretty apparent how this is going to play out; see http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/30449/is-4-5-years-the-midlife-crisis-for-a-programming-career-closed. Call it what you want, but a community-driven process it most decidedly *isn't.*

Comment: @Robert: not sure what point you were trying to make with that, but [see my answer here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/73382/please-stop-using-programmers-se-as-your-toilet-bowl/73396#73396) - I can hardly fault the SO user who moved that question when it fits in so well with what's already on P.SE.

Comment: @Shog9: It was moved by a moderator, and then closed by a moderator on PSE. That's not community action, according to your own definition. If questions are going to be migrated, and the debate about the value of those questions has not been resolved, at least let the community cast five migration votes, rather than moderators making these unilateral decisions.

Comment: @Robert: fair enough. I'll leave Bill to comment on the motivation behind that.