# What happened to "What real life bad habits has programming given you?"

Tags: discussion, specific-question, undelete-request

The question [What real life bad habits has programming given you?](//stackoverflow.com/questions/164432/what-real-life-bad-habits-has-programming-given-you-closed) 
 (10k only) is one of the all-time most popular questions on Stack Overflow.  It **had** 341 upvotes and around 157k views, but it looks like at some point it was [merged across to the Programmers Stack Exchange](//softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/31775/what-real-life-bad-habits-has-programming-given-you)… and then deleted.

If they don't want our question, can we have it back please? :-)

Comment: If it ended up on Programmers, this should probably be asked on Meta.Programmers.

Comment: Now you know why they started Programmers.  It's the SO Recycle Bin, and eventually everyone empties their Recycle Bin.

Comment: Moving it around doesn't make it a better question

Comment: @random - Who says its not a good question?  At least 341 people seem to think it is...

Comment: At least 341 people are wrong or voted because it was funny. Not because it was on topic for the site

Comment: @random: Who on Earth would delete a question that was a fantastic traffic generator and motivated community to stick around? It's like Amazon deleting a few thousands of reviews with total 157K people who'd voted on them. They wouldn't because it's what attracts people to their pages.

Comment: @developer yes, and the Spice Girls used to be hugely popular, too. Also, pornography is *very* popular -- should we allow that as well?

Comment: @Jeff, deleting something that hugely popular in retrospective wasn't the right call in my opinion. I know you believe that the value of the site is represented by questions only and people play an insignificant role, but the fact is, we have a community here and a community needs its cultural heritage to keep the feeling of togetherness. I'd appreciate if you were considering that aspect too.

Comment: I'm waiting for [@aarobot](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/141911/aarobot) with his pitchfork and torch :).

Comment: @Jeff: great, now I have an image in my head of you in the mid 90s dancing to "Wannabe".

Comment: @Jeff, you know you want to...

Comment: @systempuntoout: Didn't know about other questions. What a loss to humanity...

Comment: @Jeff: That's a nice straw man argument you offered there.

Comment: @Jeff: So is that a "no" on the pornography? Because I can't tell from context. It *would* be convenient to have one fewer window open on my desktop at all times.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

I have set up a [***graveyard***](http://www.stackprinter.com/deleted) to host part<sup>*</sup> of the rejected questions the "[deletionists](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/71731/programmers-is-about-to-go-live-which-questions-should-we-migrate)" do not want in their garden; you can find that specific question [here](http://www.stackprinter.com/export?question=1599&format=HTML&service=programmers.stackexchange&linktohome=false). [Link BROKEN. But the Wayback Machine has a [backup](http://web.archive.org/web/20100913123112/https://stackoverflow.com/questions/164432/what-real-life-bad-habits-has-programming-given-you).]

Personally, like you, I have more than a doubt that *sniping* **Legendary-Popular-TopVoted questions** *silently* and *without listening to people* is the perfect fair approach in an awesome community like this but the witch hunt is continuing so, resign yourself to that.

[image]

**Related:**
[Why was «What's your favorite “programmer” cartoon» deleted?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/73412/why-was-whats-your-favorite-programmer-cartoon-deleted)
[+500 Could you please provide the list of the recently deleted legendary questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/73455/could-you-please-provide-the-list-of-the-recently-deleted-legendary-questions)
[Set up an archive for legendary deleted questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/73226/set-up-an-archive-for-legendary-deleted-questions)
[Provide a way to retrieve deleted questions and answers](https://stackapps.com/questions/1917/provide-a-way-to-retrieve-deleted-questions-and-answers)

<sup>* unluckily the archive is not complete because [I was too late](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/73226/set-up-an-archive-for-legendary-deleted-questions/73685#73685); I have to figure it out how to import them from data dumps</sup>

Comment: Where is this question now?

Comment: @smartcaveman  http://web.archive.org/web/20100809163803/http://stackoverflow.com/questions/164432/what-real-life-bad-habits-has-programming-given-you

Comment: The provided link to the question copy on your stackprinter site is broken. (@systempuntoout)

Answer (score 8):

Sorry I mis-remembered.

It was closed as a duplicate of [this question](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/1599/what-real-life-bad-habits-has-programming-given-you) which was the original reasked.

I closed then locked it on 29th Dec. I didn't merge as with 609 answers I thought it would overwhelm the other question. My intention was for it to remain on the site but unalterable. I don't know why it was subsequently deleted. The note is that it was

> deleted Jan 1 at 0:00

which is a bit suspicious as there's no user name on that.

I'm reluctant to undelete in case I fall foul of some rules I'm not yet aware of.

Comment: Downside of *not* merging it is that all existing links break.

Comment: @Shog9 - only if the migrated question remains deleted. If no one can explain why it was deleted I'll undelete it and all the links will work again. I'll also try to remember to keep an eye on it to see if it gets deleted again.

Comment: @Shog9 umm... Why did you reopen this now, so many years after it was posted and closed? Any special reason to dig it out of its grave?

Comment: Because there are good answers here that provide a useful historical perspective on a controversy that is quickly faded from current consciousness, @Shadow.

Comment: @Shog9 even so, having the question closed has no effect on existing answers. You mean that new answer can be proper here?

Comment: I don't really know where you're coming from here, @Shadow. We don't generally close answered questions as a matter of course.

Answer (score 6):

This question doesn't meet enough of the [six guidelines for subjective questions](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/good-subjective-bad-subjective/).

It reflects a much earlier time in Stack Overflow and does not belong on the current incarnation of the site.

It does not contain enough enduring value to be retained, except as a social artifact of an earlier era.

As always, it can be retrieved from the earlier data dumps if you want access to it.

Comment: I understand that your goal is trying to make the internet a better place, but I don't believe deleting questions like these is achieving this goal.  I understand that one question won't make or break the experience, but it does set the tone of the sites.  And, they do add up.

Comment: But surely " [Punishment for breaking the build](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/211426/211461#211461) " or " [Significant new inventions in computing since 1980](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/432922) " respect those "guidelines" and are "about programming", right? Oh wait..., **you** have the best answer for the first one, and **Alan Kay** wrote the second one. We wouldn't want to annoy Alan, wouldn't we? (And I am at a loss about " [What are some funny loading statements to keep users amused?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/182112) ", and so many others)

Comment: As I said in the comments of " [Will the gold “Great Answers” badges be removed after the deletion of popular questions?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/73507/73509#73509) ", *your* site, *your* rules. I have no issue with you removing *any* question from SO following *any* criteria you have advertised. But simply deleting such popular questions remains a bit harsh (not to mention the badges issue I highlighted in my question).

Comment: If anything, they attracted their share of traffic, and could have been used, in a separate special site, as a kind of "education tool" to introduce the occasional googler to the StackExchange world that actually exists beyond those funny questions.

Comment: @vonc I simply don't agree. Start your own site and mirror those questions if you feel so strongly about them; the CC attribution encourages this. (I went ahead and deleted my answer on that question, but overall I think that question does have merit enough to keep, if you're looking for serious ways to handle build breaks)

Comment: @Jeff Your recently awarded achievement http://tinyurl.com/2vcx7jg is now sub judice :).

Comment: @Jeff but can you please *document* the deletions somewhere so we actually *can* fetch the questions later? The only real problem I have with all this is your doing it on the QT. *That* is terribly unfair

Comment: Doesn't the Recently Deleted Questions list show what's been recently deleted? @pek

Comment: @random good hint. It's a bit cumbersome to walk through but will surely help. Thanks

Comment: @Pek there's a +500 bounty waiting for you, mind to share that list?

Comment: @system aaah! I didn't realize my 10k powers would come in handy one day :) I will. Is there still some time? Seeing as I can't do it straight away?

Comment: @Pek it's ending in 2 days; you have the full weekend to work with it :).

Comment: @system that doesn't mean much at the moment, I'm working 7 days a week :) But I will go through them, there shouldn't be that many.

Comment: @Pek [come on](http://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Titanen_Atlas,_Nordisk_familjebok.png) :) . Thanks!

Comment: @systempuntoout - sorry. The "deleted" tab in the 10k tools have a 30-day view, but as I just found out, they only show deleted questions up to 1 day old nevertheless. So - we're back to square one.

Comment: @Pekka that's sad

Comment: Most useless +500 bounty investment on SO so far :). It [ended](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/73412/why-was-whats-your-favorite-programmer-cartoon-deleted) without answers.

Comment: it'd be good to link to the page of old questions.or to have a stackoverflowbin site

Answer (score 6):

I have re-posted the question on Quora, a place where these kinds of subjective questions are allowed and possibly even encouraged:

http://www.quora.com/What-real-life-bad-habits-has-programming-given-you

If you answered the original, you might be interested in giving your answer again here.

Comment: A trash bin challenger appears!

Comment: http://web.archive.org/web/20100809163803/http://stackoverflow.com/questions/164432/what-real-life-bad-habits-has-programming-given-you