# Who should be granted to Migration Path feature?

Tags: discussion, migration

Most of arguments defending the flood of bad questions on Programmers.SE is about the incapacity of SO members to handling properly the migration. See [Please stop using Programmers.SE as your toilet bowl](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/73382/please-stop-using-programmers-se-as-your-toilet-bowl).

So, who deserves the rights to use migration path?

Is it good now? PSE members disagree.

Raise granting to 30k users?

Just mods?

Drop it for all?

Apply a test to measure the capacity of the member to use this tool? (just kidding)

**"With great power comes great responsibility"**

Comment: How many of "those PSE members" are also on SO _regularly in both places_ that are complaining?

Comment: The people who are migrating the old, popular questions are *moderators.* Altering migration privileges based on rep is not going to fix that.

Comment: Still want to see hard numbers on this "flood of bad questions". Bigown, if you visit http://programmers.stackexchange.com/tools/recently-imported I think you should be able to get a quick count of the migrated questions...

Comment: @Rob: you're not a 10K user on P.SE (nor am I, or I'd just post the number myself)

Comment: @Shog9: Ouch...  I had all those privileges until the site came out of beta.

Comment: @Rob: yeah... Now that we could actually *use* them...

Comment: @Shog9: It's not a lot of questions.  The "flood" stopped when we began posting objections here, so apparently the moderators are cogitating about it.

Comment: @Rob: that's what I suspected. Given the angst, I was expecting to see SO users going hog-wild for the new option, but it's tiny in comparison to SU, SF... even Meta migrations.

Comment: @Shog9: migration started  effectively this week. Except for last 24 or 36 hours, we get many bad questions. And isn't close to 0.1% of SO will migrate to us. "Recently imported" doesn't list closed questions and I personally close a lot of them in a short period.

Comment: @bigown: without data to the contrary, I'm leaning toward Robert's theory that the bulk of the migrations were performed by SO moderators, probably in response to [the previous discussions here on Meta](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/71731/programmers-is-about-to-go-live-which-questions-should-we-migrate) - if that's the case, then changing the system for normal users is pointless, and your time would be better spent crafting a good argument in that thread for which questions should and should not be moved.

Comment: @Shog9: the most problematic questions have been made to community. But our discussion has decreased or maybe ceased the mistaken migration from mods.

Comment: @bigown: I don't understand the first sentence. The second may be true, but again, nothing you suggest (seriously) here would have made one bit of difference in that. And I would still appreciate some idea of the *magnitude* of this "flood"...

Answer (score 2):

The SO community should be educated into closing these questions in the first place, instead of migrating them, but that doesn't require changing the way it currently works.

Anyway, as they can be closed, I'm not sure it's not so much of a big deal. That is, unless the PSE has **very low traffic**, in which case that could be overwhelming (but then, is this SE worth keeping?)