# Migrating old SO questions to Programmers

Tags: discussion, migration, old-questions, software-engineering-se

I've found a fair number of old questions that obviously now belong on Programmers. However, simply voting to close doesn't seem to be doing the trick. Because they are old, no one is looking, and the vote just expires.

Is there a better way to handle these?

Comment: Please don't blindly vote to migrate. A lot of these old questions aren't really suitable for Programmers' plus it's often better to just leave them where they are.

Comment: @ChrisF - I'm voting to migrate the ones that I feel would be a good fit on Programmers (others might disagree, and that's why we have a voting system). If I think the question is worthless, I will vote to close outright. If it belongs on SO - then it's already in the right place. My question here is about getting enough attention on old questions to clean up the site.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't *think* you have an account on Programmers, so first read: **[Programmers is about to go live, which questions should we migrate?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/71731/programmers-is-about-to-go-live-which-questions-should-we-migrate)**

...And then read: **[Please stop using Programmers.SE as your toilet bowl](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/73382/please-stop-using-programmers-se-as-your-toilet-bowl)**

Reading [the P.SE FAQ](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/faq) wouldn't hurt either.

Then post a link to the question in [Regulator Headquarters](http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/rooms/227/regulator-headquarters), along with an explanation for why it should be migrated.

If that doesn't do the trick, you can always flag for moderator attention and give a good argument for why the question *needs* to be migrated...

Otherwise, accept that it can take time, and a lot of these old questions are probably better deleted than migrated.

Comment: Is 14 questions too many to dump on Regulator HQ?

Comment: @status-declined: if you have the time, go for it. No guarantees anything will happen, but it's not like there's a *lot* of traffic there normally.

Comment: Done. http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/572963#572963

Comment: Good comment, but should we not use the bathroom?

Answer (score 1):

The 10k+ user tools show lists of the [most recent close votes](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/tools?tab=close&daterange=last2days), so that will get *some* eyes on it.

Sometimes I will vote to close, maybe wait a few hours or even a day, and if I don't see much movement I'll flag it for a mod to migrate. If it's a pretty clear-cut case, you can probably just flag for a mod to handle right off the bat.

Comment: ... and if you are always right, you'll get the deputy badge!

Comment: @Juan: Well, you don't *always* have to be right. You just have to be more often right than wrong and you'll get it eventually. ;)