# Should old questions be flagged for migration?

Tags: support, migration, flags, old-questions

Should old questions that are now better asked on a different site like Superuser be tagged for migration?

Example:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48402/

Comment: Possible duplicates: [Should I flag ancient questions that need closing / migrating? \[closed\]](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/84395/155585), [Migrating old SO questions to Programmers](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/83759/155585).

Comment: From my answer of the 1st duplicate: I strongly oppose flagging for migration. **1.** As this is about ancient questions, the chances are high that in the meantime the question (or a very similar one) has been asked again on the destination site. Then the ancient question will only be seen as noise and will be closed as a duplicate (which helps noone). **2.** Migrating old (answered) questions clutters the front page of the destination site and takes away attention from new (unanswered) questions.

Comment: @hendrik your concerns are definitely valid, but sometimes the newer sites can benefit a lot from a transfusion of select questions from SO.

Comment: @Jeff: Thanks for the feedback! I'm (naturally) only talking from the point of view of tex.sx, and there I can say: Migrating _new_ questions is (mostly) good (sometimes it's a real nuisance since questions get reposted on tex.sx _and_ migrated), but I think I haven't seen a migrated _old_ question that really added value to tex.sx.

Comment: @hendrik I believe Konrad is flagging some of those so follow up with him.

Comment: @Jeff: Ah, sorry, forgot to say that, and it's an important exception: If an active user on tex.sx flags questions he contributed to, then I'm perfectly happy with this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, definitely -- but **only for *strongly* off-topic questions**. If it's a least a little bit programmery, it can be left as is.

Comment: @Jeff - Can we have a defined process for this?  I know some of the beta sites, like PMSE, probably aren't ready to have a bunch of questions dumped onto our site.  Considering we only get a few questions per day, could that clutter our home page?

Comment: @jmort per previous guidance, this only applies to sites that are NOT in beta. The OP was asking about migrating to Super User.

Comment: @Jeff, he said "asked on a different site, like Superuser...", which implies he is including other sites as well.  Thanks for reaffirming that questions should not be moved to beta sites so that other users don't stumble upon this and think otherwise :)

Comment: @jmort i'm not averse to occasionally migrating a question to a beta site if it is an INSANELY SUPER MEGA INCREDIBLY AWESOME fit to that site .. and it wouldn't tend to get a good answer on SO anyways.

Comment: Now, wait, are you suggesting this for questions that already have accepted answers as well?

Comment: @Will: In that case I _strongly_ oppose migration. See my comments to the question.