# It's a shame that Stack Overflow broke up

Tags: discussion

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why was the Programmers site on Stack Exchange created?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64042/why-was-the-programmers-site-on-stack-exchange-created)

Moderators are too hard on questions on Stack Overflow that overlap with some of the other newer Stack Exchange sites, which have very little users at this time. It's a catch-22, though, because if you don't encourage people to use these offbeat sites, then the user count will remain low. I personally don't see the value in Security, Server Fault, and Programmers.  Why can't we just keep everything on Stack Overflow?  Programmers wear many hats and the parts make the whole.

Comment: Huh? Your questions got plenty of votes. What is your issue?

Comment: Programmers.SE has a niche.. look closer

Comment: The point of this was that the moderators are too hard on people who post on the wrong medium.  I do appreciate the down-votes, though.

Comment: @Bradford: Moderators are doing those people a favor by moving their question to a site where experts are more likely to answer it.

Comment: +1 for the topic edit.  It's a much better title.  +1 to the 10 downvotes.  And +1 for the StackExchange network being one of my top 5 visited and favorite "sites".

Comment: I didn't know they were a band. *::rimshot::*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check the [Stack Exchange site directory](https://stackexchange.com/sites).  Server Fault has 64k users and 92k questions, so it's not exactly small.  Programmers and IT Security *are* small, but they both have a 99% answered rate. Focusing experts' attention on niche topics seems to be working.

Answer (score 4):

When stackoverflow started, it had very few users on it too.  Give them time and a little attention, and they'll grow up to be just as useful in their own right as stack overflow is.

Keep in mind that each site is meant to attract the *experts* of that topic.

Security experts don't necessarily want to wade through 99% programming questions to find the few security questions that they are interested in - they'll go to another forum that meets their needs.  Why not set up a forum that's just for them, where 99% of the questions are interesting to them?

Yes, they are small and just getting started, but questions are getting answers, and just because it takes awhile to grow is no reason to not allow it to grow.

Comment: But you can filter questions (otherwise you get >10 new question per minute you are not really interested)